# WebForms, Angular 7, WebAPI, and IdentityServer 3

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, webforms, identityserver3

I have a website (developed by a third party but I have the source) that uses WebForms and currently authenticates with Forms. I've built an Angular 7 application that is launched from a page in this website. I also have a WebAPI resource that both the WebForms website and the Angular application need to make use of. As part of this third party software suite I also have an IdentityServer3 implementation (it's currently used to secure a different stand-alone API) that authenticates to the same database as the Webforms website.  Is the best course of action to replace the Forms Authentication on the WebForms website with IdentityServer authentication and also use IdentityServer to authenticate the Angular app and then it should single sign on? Do I have to use the same flow with both to get SSO? Also I believe I have to redirect from the IdentityServer login page back to the WebForms website since I've read you lose SSO if you use grantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword but I'd like to verify that's true.

Above is the route I've been going down but is there another good option?  I recently saw an Angular.js app embedded in a .NET website authenticating with Forms to WebAPI. I don't have the source so I'm not exactly sure what's going on in .NET land but is this an option?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe I misread something, but why does the third party website have identity server 3 if it doesn't use it for authentication? Are you sure it isn't already using it?

Comment: Ha, I left that out on purpose because it's a long winded explanation that has to do with requirements for a certification for the type of software it is (medical). They should have integrated it but they didn't, or haven't yet possibly. The website came first and the API later on and for a completely different certification requirement.